# How can I print "ABCDabcd" with these class constructors?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, virtual-functions

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A"; }
    A(const A&) { cout << "a"; }
};

class B : public virtual A {
public:
    B() { cout << "B"; }
    B(const B&) { cout << "b"; }
};

class C : public virtual A {
public:
    C() { cout << "C"; }
    C(const C&) { cout << "c"; }
};

class D : B, C {
public:
    D() { cout << "D"; }
    D(const D&) { cout << "d"; }
};
```

And I want to create a `D` object and have it print `"ABCDabcd"`.

I tried this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

But it only prints `"ABCD"`, and I don't know how to call the rest of the code.

Any idea?

Comment: Yes,I am sure about "ABCDabcd"

Comment: I can tell that the "ABCD" part is to demosntrate constructors. I do not see anything which should cause the "abcd" part (that is why I was thinking of destructors). So please explain what "i want to print "ABCDabcd"" means for the actual goal you want to achieve. I.e. why is `cout << "ABCDabcd";` not an answer? What do the lower case letter output mean? I suspect that they are meant to be triggered by casting, but nothing in `main()` or elsewhere seems likely to be able to trigger that.

Comment: I suspect that part of the shown code is "non-editable" and part is "editable" by your assignment, please explain that.

Comment: Look at your code and figure out how `ABCD` gets printed. Once you understand that, look at what analogous thing would cause `abcd` to be printed. For example, what causes `a` to be printed?

Comment: Why is `cout << "ABCDabcd";` not an answer? I think you forgot to explain some of the rules....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ABCD` portion of the output you see is being printed by the [*default constructors*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.  When `main()` constructs the `D` object, it is invoking `D`'s default constructor, which invokes `A`, `B`, and `C`'s default constructors.

The `abcd` portion of the output that is missing is printed by the [*copy constructors*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` instead. So `main()` needs to *make a copy* of the `D` object in order to invoke `D`'s copy constructor, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    D d;
    D d2{d}; // or: D d2 = d;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/i2Wckl)

However, you will notice that the output of this copy will be `ABCd` rather than `abcd` as expected.  This is because `D`'s copy constructor does not invoke the copy constructors of `A`, `B`, or `C`, it invokes their default constructors instead.

To fix that, you need to add a [**member initialization list**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to each copy constructor in order to call non-default base constructors, eg:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A"; }
    A(const A&) { cout << "a"; }
};

class B : public virtual A {
public:
    B() { cout << "B"; }
    B(const B &b) : A(b) { cout << "b"; }
};

class C : public virtual A {
public:
    C() { cout << "C"; }
    C(const C &c) : A(c) { cout << "c"; }
};

class D : public B, C {
public:
    D() { cout << "D"; }
    D(const D &d) : A(d), B(d), C(d) { cout << "d"; }
};
```

Then the copy will print `abcd` as expected.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/TMCVDV)

Comment: @Yunnosch The copy constructors will not produce the desired output unless they are altered as I described, otherwise [the output will be `"ABCDABCd"` instead](https://ideone.com/i2Wckl). There is no getting around that in this use-case.

Comment: I am afraid you are right. But if writing any code which gets the desired output is the goal then I start with `cout << "ABCDabcd";`.... Something is missing. But I blame the question, not your answer....